# Parsing type dns.RR

Tags: go, parsing, dns

I'm new to Go and trying to get a small DNS program working that parses returned A and CNAME records.  This is using github.com/miekg/dns package.

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly parse the returned resource record for A or CNAME.  For the A record, I want to get the IP address and store it in a variable.  For the CNAME that has multiple RRs returned, I'd like to parse the Name and Address fields and store in variables.

I've tried converting the structure to a string or unpacking it to no avail.  Anyone can lend any insight, greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code below.  Text file contains a single line with 'www':

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "github.com/miekg/dns"
)

func dns_request_fwd(s string) []dns.RR {
    //fmt.Println(s, " : started processing DNS request")

    m1 := new(dns.Msg)
    m1.Id = dns.Id()
    m1.RecursionDesired = true
    m1.Question = make([]dns.Question, 1)
    m1.Question[0] = dns.Question{s, dns.TypeA, dns.ClassINET}
    in, err := dns.Exchange(m1, "8.8.8.8:53")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if len(in.Answer) > 0 {
        //fmt.Println("Response greater than 0 - got something!")
        //fmt.Println(in.Answer)
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("Empty DNS Response")
        return nil
    }

    if _, ok := in.Answer[0].(*dns.A); ok {

        //fmt.Println("Detected an 'A' record Answer.  Returning RR!")
        return in.Answer

    } else if _, ok := in.Answer[0].(*dns.CNAME); ok {
        //fmt.Println("Detected a 'CNAME' record Answer.  Returning RR!")
        return in.Answer

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Returning nil")
        return nil

    }

}

func main() {

    f, err := os.Open("list4.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    domain := "acme.com"
    domain_lookup := "." + domain + "." 

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {

    a_record := scanner.Text()

    lookup := a_record+domain_lookup
    fmt.Println("Looking up: ", lookup)
    dreq := dns_request_fwd(lookup)
    if len(dreq) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("    [+] Forward Lookup answer")
        if _, ok := dreq[0].(*dns.CNAME); ok {
            fmt.Println("    [+] Type is CNAME")
                //fmt.Println(dreq[0].(*dns.CNAME))
            //fmt.Println(dreq[1].(*dns.A))
            fmt.Println("    [+] Alias records: ", len(dreq) -1)

            // Iterate through returned alias A records
            for i, s := range dreq {
                if i == 0{
                    //Do nothing because first record is repeat of request 
                } else {
                    // Need to parse the below RR to get the Name + IP address returned
                    fmt.Println("    [+] Returned",i, s)
                    fmt.Println(s[0])
                }
            }

        } else if _, ok := dreq[0].(*dns.A); ok {

            fmt.Println("    [+] Type is A")
            // Need to parse the below RR to get the IP address returned
            fmt.Println("    [+] Answer: ", dreq[0])

        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println("    [-] We Got Nothing")
    }
    

    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "parse" a struct. The library parsed the response already in order to give you the struct. Just use the fields in the struct which have the data you want, like [`dns.A.A` which is a `net.IP`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/miekg/dns#A) or [`dns.CNAME.Target` which is a `string`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/miekg/dns#CNAME). See [the package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/miekg/dns) for more details.

```
if arec, ok := dreq[0].(*dns.A); ok {
    fmt.Println("    [+] Type is A")
    fmt.Println("    [+] Answer: ", arec.A)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I should have stated that I was having trouble using the structure and accessing the fields rather than "parse" the structure - as you correctly stated.  With that said, I think my issue was I was trying to run this below when checking the CNAME and A record, and I was getting an error of "dns.RR has no field or method A".  Example for checking CNAME:
```
if _, ok := dreq[0].(*dns.CNAME); ok {
```

Comment: Right, because you're using the interface type after checking its underlying type, instead of using the underling type. See the code sample in the answer, it replaces `_, ok` with `arec, ok` and then references `arec`, which is typed. See https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What is up with the down votes on this?  Did I violate some etiquette?  I'm a beginner to golang and said that from the beginning.  I tried looking at the mkrieg documentation prior to asking the question.  I couldn't find what I was looking for due to my lack of familiarity with go and how to use fields in the struct.  I thought this is what stackoverflow is for.